# Matzah eruvin on erev Pesach

Tags: shabbat, food, passover, matzah, eruv-chatzerot

An eruv allows Jews to carry within a semi-public space on Shabbat.  The space must be bounded by walls and must meet several detailed requirements.  The eruv must consist of food for a meal for the community that shares that semi-public space.

Most cities or towns that have an eruv use matzah for their eruvs - it's cheap, it never goes bad (well, it never goes *worse*) and you can eat it all year (just make sure to replace it on Passover).  But there is one time you cannot eat matzah - erev Pesach.

**If erev Pesach falls on Shabbos, how can a community sustain its eruv with matzah (even matzah for that year)?**

I once asked a very knowledgeable rabbi this, but I found the answer unsatisfying.  He said this:

- If you made an eruv of a meal for Friday night and it is eaten fully, the eruv remains valid.  If you made an eruv of a meal for Friday night and it is not eaten but spoils, the eruv remains valid since it *was edible* at some point.
- You can technically eat matzah during bein hashmashot - after Shabbos starts, and before the d'oraita ban on matzah starts.
- You can therefore make a meal of matzah during bein hashmashot
- Since the matzah is edible for that meal (you know - the one we intend to eat when we start shabbos so early that we're home from shul, make kiddush, wash, and eat fully by twilight?), it's fine.

I am dissatisfied by this because that meal does not actually exist. I am also dissatisfied because it relies on two definitions of "night" in order to work.  It feels strategic rather than genuine.

**Is there a better answer as to why using matzah for an eruv on erev Pesach is valid?**

Comment: No way! I just asked this question to a friend two days ago!

Comment: Your dissatisfaction with the rabbi's answer presupposes that the prohibition begins at night, which is actually a point of disagreement. While some rishonim hold the prohibition starts at night (including possibly the Ramban and Orchos Chayim), other rishonim hold that the prohibition doesn't start until dawn (which is generally how we hold), and some hold that it doesn't start until chametz becomes prohibited.

Comment: @Fred That's what my friend and I decided the answer was.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, this question also occurred to me a couple years ago. Back then, I was additionally thinking along the lines of considering the nature of the prohibition against eating matza versus the nature of the need to use food that can be eaten. For example, would someone who knows he won't be able to eat matza on Pesach be allowed to eat matza on Erev Pesach? (+1 on the question, by the way).

Comment: @Fred Thanks for the clarification. Sounds like there's an answer in there, though I'd also want to see what those who hold that the prohibition starts at night would say. Or maybe they'd just make eruvin from matzah balls.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Incidentally, I think there's some disagreement regarding eating matzah balls on Erev Pesach, too. Then there's the issue for those who avoid gebrochts on Pesach....

Comment: Isn't the entire construct of 'Eruv strategic?

Comment: Also, sorry to nitpick, but, "bein hashmoshim?"

Comment: @SethJ yes, but we're usually more creative than using an accidental hour.  and no worries about picking nits... but you can just edit it yourself.

Comment: Of course, they can just use bread and eat it in the morning.

Comment: If the reason to prefer matzah is economic/convenience, then surely for one Shabbat a year (in years where it applies) we can just use bread instead as @DoubleAA says?  Is there actually a halachic reason to prefer matzah, or is it just convenient (and when it's not convenient, don't do that)?

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment - The *Orchos Chayim* ([*Hil. Chametz uMatzah* 114](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23994&st=&pgnum=148)) does not rule that the prohibition starts at night, but he does mention that there are rishonim who hold this way.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The Rama says it's always only a convenience issue. I don't know of anyone who argues.

Comment: What's wrong with the first answer the Rov gave (issue of the night.)

Comment: @Yehoshua as I stated in my question: `I am dissatisfied by this because that meal does not actually exist. I am also dissatisfied because it relies on two definitions of "night" in order to work. It feels strategic rather than genuine.`

Comment: Your main point is that the eiruv needs to be edible by all people and at any time of the day?

Comment: @Yehoshua certainly by all people.  Any time of day? no, but more than just that hour for a meal that doesn't exist.  If someone posts the answer that matzah is allowed in the morning, I could accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) See shulchan Aruch end of Siman 416 that Yom Kippur also requires an Eiruv and it is valid (and we all know that we won't be able to eat it at all on YK!), I think that YK would be a stronger question.

2) In Shulchan Aruch HoRav 386:8 he writes משתתפין אפילו באוכל שאינו ראוי לו אם ראוי לשום אדם מישראל, now since Min Hatorah a child is allowed to eat on Yom Kippur (see SA HoRav  Siman 394:2 that the restrictions are only if forbidden from Torah Law) and definitely on Erev Pesach that's on Shabbos it's not Min HaTorah even for an adult. In addition by Yom Kippur, a sick person -let's say a woman within 3 days after giving birth- may eat it - therefore there would be no problem with the Eiruv.

Comment: Accept because of point 2.  Yom Kippur eruvin really clarify things.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[HaMaor Volume 33:3 page 24 - Rabbi Shmuel Singer](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=27987&st=&pgnum=24&hilite=) asks this question and says that since the [Rama 471:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=160) indicates that a minor can eat Matza therefore you can make this Eruv.

Comment: 1) How would that help? 2) The Rama doesn't say that. He says it isn't assur to _feed_ them because it's only a bittul aseh. The food is still assur, just we don't have a prohibition of feeding minors something only forbidden as bittul aseh. See the Terumat haDeshen the Rama quotes.

Comment: @DoubleAA did you read the first line?

Comment: Of the Rama? Yes. Did you? He says להאכילו==to feed him. Like I said, see the Rama's source (the Terumat haDeshen) inside to understand him better.