# Can egg Matzo be used to make an Eruv Chatzeiros on Pesach?

Tags: passover, ashkenazi, bread, eruv-chatzerot

Inspired by [Matzah eruvin on erev Pesach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26820/matzah-eruvin-on-erev-pesach/26834#26834)

Can egg Matzo be used to make an Eruv Chatzeiros on Pesach? On Pesach, Ashkenazim do not eat egg Matzo; however, it is not Chometz. In certain instances it may be eaten. Would there be a problem using it for an Eruv on a Shabbos that falls on Pesach, such as Shabbos Chol HaMoed?

Comment: Why specifically Eruvei Chatzeiros? Do you think the answer would be different by Eiruvei Techumin or Eruvei Tavshilin?

Answer (score 2):

The mishna said in the 3nd chapter of Eruvin mishna 1-2:

> מְעָרְבִין לְנָזִיר בְּיַיִן וּלְיִשְׂרָאֵל בִּתְרוּמָה ... מְעָרְבִין בִּדְמַאי

We can make an Eruv for a nazir by wine, for Yisroel by teruma, with Demai. The demai is not really allowed for a not poor neeman man. But it is good for Eruv.
We can assume that Egg Matsa is not considered as prohibited as Chomets, some people do not eat this by minhag. May be that it is similar to Demai from this point of view. The cases of Nazir which can ""Lehishael" and truma which can too,  are perhaps an additional proof for the Egg Matso minhag which can also be nish'al. I heard that the Steipeler זצוק"ל was stringent to eat "not Gebrocht". When his spouse deceased, he was invited to his daughter. When he saw that she made stringent efforts to make not gebrocht, when in her home they was eating Gebrocht, the Steipeler has decided to make Hatarat nedarim and started to eat gebrocht.

So Eruve Chatserot with eggs Matsot are  apparently good enough . Nobody think that egg Matsa is prohibited,  the  minhag may be changed by hatarat Nedarim,  nobody is  nishba mehar Sinai.  Efshar Lehishael.

I am duty to @Double AA for indicating this post.

Comment: @Double AA what do you think?

Comment: I don't follow the relationship between Egg Matza and being Matir Neder to eat Gebrocht. If you left out whole section of the Steipeler what would change about your answer?

Comment: @Yishai if it is not  chamets,  hatarat nedarim would not help?

Comment: If it was chametz according to all opinions, it wouldn't help. But either way, what does that have to do with egg matza? A source that you can be nishal about egg matza, especially an ashkenazi, would be more helpful.

Comment: @Ylshai is there a problem with this minhag different than the problem of gebrocht,  hatarat nedarimly speaking?