# Children eating Matzah on Erev Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, minor-katan-child, matzah

Is it permitted for children to eat Matzah on Erev Pesach? Does it matter whether they will be awake for the Seder or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R Israel Isserlein was asked this question. Here is his response ([Terumat HaDeshen #125](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%9F/%D7%90/%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%94)):

> קטן בערב פסח, שרי להאכילו מצות או לאו?‏
>
> תשובה: ייראה, דאם לא הגיע הקטן לכלל דעת כל כך שיודע ומבין מה שמספרים לו מניסים ונפלאות ביציאת מצרים, שרי להאכילו. ואף על פי דאסרו חכמים לגדול אכילת מצה בערב פסח מזמן איסור חמץ ואילך, וקיימא לן דלא ספינן בידיים איסור לקטן, הא חולק מהר"ם בהלכות ברכות שלו, דהני מילי באיסור לאו, אבל ביטול מצות עשה ספינן ליה. ובזה יישב המנהג שנהגו להטעים התינוקות מן הקידוש בבית הכנסת, ועיין שם. והרי נידון דידן נמי אין האיסור אלא משום ביטול ופגם המצות. אך קשה קצת חילוק דמהר"ם, דבפרק חרש בגמרא (יבמות קיד א) פריך למאן דאמר מצווין להפריש, מכהן קטן שאוכל תרומה טמאה, ומאי דפריך התם ליכא אלא איסור עשה, כדפירש רש"י התם בהדיא, דאתיא "ובשעריך תאכלנו", לזה ולא לאחר. ויש לחלק בין איסור הבא מכלל עשה ובין ביטול פגם מצות עשה. אמנם אם הגיע הקטן שיוכל להבין כדלעיל, נראה דאין להאכילו מצה, דדרשינן: "והגדת לבנך" כו', ו"בעבור זה", לא אמרתי אלא בשעה שיש מצה ומרור מונחים לפניך, ואם ימלא הבן כבר כריסו מן המצות, היאך שייך לומר "בעבור זה", כיון דאין המצה חידוש לו לקטן?‏
>
> A minor on Erev Pesach, can one feed him Matzot or not?
>
> Response: It seems that if the minor has not attained a sufficient intellect so as to know and understand what they are telling him about the miracles and wonder of the Exodus, it is permitted to feed him. Even though the Sages forbade and adult eating Matza on Erev Pesach after the time when Chametz is prohibited, and we hold that we can't manually provide forbidden products to a minor, R Meir [of Rothenberg] distinguished in his *Laws of Blessings* that that applies to a negative prohibition, but objects which nullify a positive command one can give him [...] and our case is also a prohibition based on nullification and diminishment of a Mitzva. [...] However if the minor has attained a sufficient intellect to understand as above, it seems one shouldn't feed him Matza, for we expound: "'And you should tell your sons...' and 'Because of this...', this only applies when Matza and Maror lay in front of you," and if the son fills his belly with Matza [earlier], how can one say "Because of this" since the Matza is not new to him?

Rama cites this ruling in [OC 471:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%90_%D7%91).

Comment: "R Israel Isserlein was asked this question." The acharonic tradition was that he made up the questions.

Comment: @Alex Ya I know, but is there really proof for that?

Comment: Unlikely. The Shach, Sha'ar Ephraim, and Beis Shmuel simply assert it. (The Shach says it is נודע and the Sha'ar Ephraim says it is גלוי ומפורסם.)

Comment: @Alex I believe (if I recall correctly) I heard Rav Asher Weiss say the introduction to shibalei leket (his talmid) proves the questions were real

Comment: @robev do you mean the leket yosher? Shibbolei haleket was much earlier

Answer (score 2):

[Star K website](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/seasonal/357/the-busiest-day-of-the-year-the-laws-of-erev-pesach/) says a child under the age of six may eat Matza on Erev Pesach.

> A child under the age of six may eat matzoh even on Erev Pesach.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26834/759